# Cannot rake db:migrate (Pin error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

i'm working on the One Month Rails app and I recently run into this error when i try to `run rake db: migrate`:

[image]

Here is what my migration file looks like:

[image]

Any help on how to solve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: whats your version number of your migration file that you tried to run?

Comment: The version number is 20140418122310

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with specifying the version and run.

```
rake:db:migrate VERSION = your_file_version
```

In your case,it is

```
rake:db:migrate VERSION = 20140418122310
```

**Edit**

In your migration file change this line

```
create_table :pins do |t|
```

to like this

```
change_table :pins do |t|
```

Comment: @Bendik Are you having any duplicate migration file of same name `create_pins`?

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe this migration file has anything to with the error: http://gyazo.com/9a4830e6de21c5490cb5c756e6e5a401

Comment: Yes, I tried to change the line in the migration file, but it gave me a new error: http://gyazo.com/d6526a6a2787aeebfd44077283b3a5ae

Comment: @Bendik do `rake:db:rollback` and try again.

Comment: @Bendik can you tell me the names of those three?

Comment: Ok: create_pins, add_User_id_to_pins and add_attachment_image_to_pins

Comment: @Bendik How the create_pins look like? Can you post it.?

Comment: @Bendik Why do you have this line `Pin.reset_column_information` in your `add_User_id_to_pins` migration file?

Comment: I have no idea. I guess I've just followed the course blindly

Comment: @Bendik Try removing that line from that file and try again.

Comment: @Bendik Try from scratch and follow these guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html For now,accept my answer and move on